# External ColdFusion 9 server

Tags: coldfusion

I have an IIS server running a stand-alone install of ColdFusion9 with many customer sites.  For high availability, I am trying to connect my web server to an external clustered multi-instance ColdFusion server.

In testing, I found that I had to copy the .cfm files from my web server to the instance directories of the external server.  This is going to be impossible to implement on my production sites.  Is there any way to utilize an external CF server with the .cfm files residing on the web server?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to do this, though my experience with having CF on a different server than the web server is somewhat limited.  Essentially, when the request is handed off to CF, the CF engine needs to have access to the .cfm files that are being executed which is why you need to have a copy of them available to the instance that's executing them.  It would be like trying to execute a program over remote desktop except that DLLs needed by the program weren't installed on that remote system but on your own box.  That program can't run unless its DLLs are installed on the box it's running on.  Likewise with CF, the engine/instance needs to have copies of the .cfm files in order to execute them.

You might also try asking on the cf-talk mailing list at houseoffusion.com as there are some CF server wizards there that may not be looking here on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

That is the case. I believe the Web server connector just hands the CF service the filesystem path for the file to be executed along with the various Web server environment variables.

You could always:

1) keep all your CF files on a SAN volume or network share, and mount that volume on your CF servers, or
2) use some sort of filesync service to synchronize the files across the servers

The nice thing about 1) is you could mount the filesystem as read-only as a security measure.... your CF server rarely if ever needs to have write privileges to your application files.